# Gluing of algebras meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra

Often in physics papers, I have seen the words, 'gluing of algebras'.
What does it mean to glue two algebras together along a common representation? Can you please explain this in simple terms (that can be understood by a non-mathematical physicist.)

Comment: To give a reference, see Definition $3$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910031.pdf).